# Issue while converting timeStamp to local Time Zone Date

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a timestamp generated from [Here](https://currentmillis.com/)

```
//Timestamp  1473163200000
```

I want to convert it inot Date Object based on Current Time Zone.

I am doing this as:

```
NSDate *gmtDate  = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1473163200000/1000];
NSTimeInterval timeZoneOffset = [[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] secondsFromGMTForDate:gmtDate];




NSDate *localDate = [gmtDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:timeZoneOffset];
```

Now when I `po` local Date I get this:

```
  (lldb) po localDate
   2016-09-06 17:30:00 +0000
```

When I use DateFormatter to Log `localDate`

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss"];
NSString *newDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:localDate];
```

I am getting this:

```
(lldb) po newDate
2016-09-06-23-00-00
```

But I want this to be:

```
    Tue Sep 06 2016 17:30:00
```

What I am missing ?
Please avoid formatting i am more curious about time zone.

Comment: In your dateFormatter, give him your local, and also the dateFormat does not match the format you want.

Comment: `NSString *newDate = @"Tue Sep 06 2016 17:30:00";` BTW: What you are doing with the timezone is conceptual wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1473163200000/1000];

NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss";
NSString *formattedDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: date];

NSLog(@"formattedDate: %@",formattedDate);
```

Output:

```
formattedDate: Tue Sep 06 2016 17:30:00
```

Comment: what is EEE for ?

Comment: To show the 3 first letter of the week day, since you wanted to show "Tue". See there: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns